# working with ashx file get current user aspnet membership provider

Tags: asp.net

I have picture  and i set it's source like this:

```
img.ImageUrl = "~/BackFile.ashx?group=" + getsrc();
```

And in my ashx file I need to write something like this

```
var picturerecord= (from p in pdc.groups
where p.username = Page.User.IdentityName.ToString()
select p)
```

But  Page.User.IdentityName.ToString()  doesn't work there.
so how can I get current username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're not able to get the user is because you're not inside a page.
You could get it from the context though:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```